# Break Down Django Query object (Q)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

After doing a query in a Django script I wrote, I was given this Q object.

`<Q: (AND: ('lesson_object_id__in', [322, 327, 328, 329, 330, 332, 1120, 1176]))>`

I want to break down that Q object so I only have the list `[322, 327, 328, 329, 330, 332, 1120, 1176]`. How would I go by doing that? Thanks

Comment: Like `list(your_queryset)` ???

Comment: When I do `list` on my Q object it says "'Q' object is not iterable". I store the Query in a variable called `lesson_ids`. Doing `list(lesson_ids)` results in that error

Comment: Wait nevermind - I had it wrapped in the Q() parentheses. That fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Oh, you had a Q object and I thought you had a Queryset. A Q object is just a fragment that can be used as an argument to the filter method of a Queryset. Unless you are doing an `or`, you don't really need a Q object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it wrapped in the Q() parentheses. Duplicating the query and storing it in the variable `list(lesson_ids)` fixed it.